# Cursor should be at start of Email Intent Content

Tags: android, textview

I am using following intent to send a support mail :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: support@abc.in"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Feedback for ABC Android " + Utils.getAppVersionName());
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n\nBelow information is" +
        "App Version - " + Utils.getAppVersionName() + "\n" +
        "OS Version - " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "\n" +
        "API Level - " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "\n" +
        "Device Model - " + android.os.Build.MODEL + "\n" +
        "Device Manufacturer - " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send through..."));
```

It works correctly and opens E-mail chooser. But Cursor comes at the end of 
EXTRA_TEXT content. I want Cursor to be at start of this content. Can i specify this somehow???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But Cursor comes at the end of EXTRA_TEXT ie content

Where the text entry cursor goes is up to the app that the user chooses for handling your `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent`. It could be at the beginning, the end, some random location, or simply not be there (because the email body widget does not have the focus).

> Can i specify this somehow?

No.